# Tracking page views when item is out of stock

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

I want to track page views of items that are out of stock using Google Tag Manager events.

My trigger in GTM is based on the visibility of an element on the page (the out of stock notice). My event and tag are set to fire once per page. These conditions appear to be working properly.

At present, if I navigate to a product that is in stock, then the tag does not fire. If I then navigate to an item that is out of stock, the tag fires.

**However:** After viewing an out of stock item, as I continue to browse other in-stock items on the website, the event seems to persist as I can see in Google Analytics that my page view count displaying this event continue to rise for items that are not in stock.

I must have something configured wrong or misunderstand how something works.

I looked for solutions like ending an event or resetting the status of an event to no avail. What else should I consider?

**EDIT:**
Here is how my tag looks:
[image]

And here is my trigger:
[image]

Comment: show your work.

Comment: Images added to the original post.

Comment: Can you change the trigger? To a regular pageview, but then have a CJS variable checking if the product is out of stock. Aslo try to find the indication of a product being out of stock in state rather than parsing it from dom. On the other hand, you could fix it by changing the selector for your text. Looks like the front-end keeps it in  DOM after it first appears and then just adds something like display:none to it when the product is available. Debug further to know for sure.

Comment: @BNazaruk, I could change the trigger to page view and try a CJS variable. However, you are correct, the element is in the DOM and then shown when it applies. I guess I was under the impression that the Element Visibility trigger fired if the element itself was visible. Not sure how to find the indication of the item being out of stock from a state. I think my next try will be to trigger page view and then use a CJS variable to determine the current style property of the element containing the out of stock message.

Comment: yes, that would be what I would've done. The only real problem with that is if pageview fires before the information about product availability appears on the page. That way you won't be able to detect whether it's there. The rest should be trivial. Using the element visibility trigger is not a good idea. It's very heavy. Avoiding it is a good practice. Using it is a hack.